# Exibir Campo ao Selecionar Dropdownlist e savar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte cenário: em um `form` tenho um campo chamado *Carga-Horaria*, que é um *Dropdownlist* com uma lista de cargas horárias. Neste drop uma opção chamada outra. Quando selecionado a opção "Outra" é aberto um novo campo para ser digitado esta nova carga horária.

Eu consegui fazer isso normalmente com o JavaScript no meu `form`.

A questão é, eu gostaria de que quando for salvo no banco, ao invés de ter uma coluna chamada, "Outra Carga-Horaria", eu gostaria de salvar este dado na coluna `Carga-Horaria` já existente.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_CHoraria, "Carga Horaria Semanal", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Nr_CHoraria, new List<SelectListItem>
             {
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "12", Value="12"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "20", Value="20"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "24", Value="24"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "30", Value="30"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "36", Value="36"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "40", Value="40"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "44", Value="44"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "Outra", Value="0"}
             }, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ch" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_CHoraria)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:none" id="div_dch">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_CHoraria, "Digite a Carga Horaria", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nr_CHoraria, new { @class = "chs", @id = "dch" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_CHoraria)
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ch').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == '0') {
                $('#div_dch').show();

            } else {
                $('#div_dch').hide();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

O correto é você separar os nomes dos campos de carga horária sugerida e outra carga horária. Algo assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CargaHoraria, "Carga Horaria Semanal", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CargaHoraria, new List<SelectListItem>
             {
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "12", Value="12"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "20", Value="20"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "24", Value="24"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "30", Value="30"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "36", Value="36"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "40", Value="40"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "44", Value="44"},
                 new SelectListItem() {Text = "Outra", Value="0"}
             }, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ch" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CargaHoraria)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:none" id="div_dch">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OutraCargaHoraria, "Digite a Carga Horaria", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OutraCargaHoraria, new { @class = "chs", @id = "dch" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OutraCargaHoraria)
    </div>
</div>
```

O que eu faria no seu lugar é um *ViewModel*:

```
public class CargaHorariaViewModel
{
    public int CargaHoraria { get; set; }
    public int? OutraCargaHoraria { get; set; }
}
```

O *Controller* receberia este *ViewModel*:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CriarCargaHoraria(CargaHorariaViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var cargaHoraria = new CargaHoraria();
        if (viewModel.CargaHoraria > 0)
            cargaHoraria.Nr_CHoraria = viewModel.CargaHoraria;
        else {
            if (viewModel.OutraCargaHoraria == null) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("OutraCargaHoraria", "Se outra carga horária será informada, o valor de Outra Carga Informada não pode ser nulo. ");
                return View(viewModel);
            }

            cargaHoraria.Nr_CHoraria = (int)viewModel.OutraCargaHoraria;
        }

        // Coloque o resto da lógica aqui.
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```